# C# Jquery Filtering on a dataGrid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datagrid

I programmatically generated `dataGrid` column headers as filters and I'm trying to filter client side using `jQuery`.
I don't understand why my filters don't work properly and while I'm clicking on the dataGrid (I need the post back) the first row in the grid "disappears".

**Server side:**

```
protected void GridTest_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
    for (int i = 0; i < GridTest.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
        TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
        txtSearch.Attributes["placeholder"] = GridTest.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        txtSearch.CssClass = "search_textbox";
        txtSearch.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        cell.Controls.Add(txtSearch);
        row.Controls.Add(cell);
    }
    GridTest.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(1, row);
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.search_textbox').each(function (i) {
                $(this).quicksearch("[id*=GridTest] tr:not(:has(th))", {
                    'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {
                        return $(row).children(":eq(" + i + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
                <div class="row" style="padding-top: 6px">
                    <div class="col-md-12" id="boxGrid">
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGridNoAlign" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"
                            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" EmptyDataText="empty" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                            OnSorting="GridTest_Sorting" DataKeyNames="Nome, Cognome, Cellulare"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridTest_OnSelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="GridTest_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="GridTest_DataBound" AllowSorting="true" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="11pt">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" DataField="Cognome" HeaderText="Cognome" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Cognome" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" DataField="Nome" HeaderText="Nome" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Nome" HeaderStyle-CssClass="alignRight" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" DataField="Fonte" HeaderText="Fonte" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Fonte" HeaderStyle-CssClass="alignRight" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" DataField="Stato" HeaderText="Stato" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Stato" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" DataField="Consulente" HeaderText="Consulente" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Consulente" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" DataField="Omaggio" HeaderText="Omaggio" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Omaggio" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" DataField="Cellulare" HeaderText="Cellulare" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Cellulare" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" DataField="DataAppuntamento" HeaderText="Data Appuntamento" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="DataAppuntamento" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblIdS" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdS")%>'> </asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblIdM" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdM")%>'> </asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Can you post the html output of the page you have used the data grid on?

Comment: Nope :( and I don't understand why after the psotback the grid doesn't generate correctly

Comment: what does the grid look like after that postback?

Comment: The first row appears empty and the filters are not generated

Comment: UPDATE: Now the headers/fitlers are generated properly, I miss the method that created it in the selectedindexchanged event, but the first row still empty